# How to filter json array based on multiple options

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swift4

I want to filter an array based on multiple switches/checkbox

**Here's what i have:**

- A UIViewController with a TableView in it
- I fetch a json request with Alamofire in an NSArray
- I fill my TableView with that array

**Here's what i want to do (but don't know how to get there):**

- I want to click a button that displays a popup
- This popup will contain 6-7 switches/checkbox and a submit button
- I will check one or more switches and click the submit button which allows me to return to the previous Controller with the filtered data.

**Example of my case:**

I have a list of restaurants that i want to filter based on these filters :

**1.**

[image: Screen Shot]

**2.**

[image: Screen Shot]

PS: The search bar works fine based on the restaurant name.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please add a sample JSON data with your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` function for your requirement, for example, if you have the response in `array` and each object has `type` key, then

```
let filteredArray = array.filter({ $0.type == "wifi" || $0.type == "parking" || $0.type == "debitcard" || $0.type == "alcohol" || $0.type == "climatisation" || $0.type == "terrace"})
```

Now populate your table view with `filteredArray`